# how do I make JOOQ + Gradle work in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jooq

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-gradle/

I use JOOQ, Spring boot, MySql, Gradle.

From here I was able to make my build.gradle script which builds successfully but doesn't seem to create any pojo classes.

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
      /* See above for the correct groupId */
      classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.18.0'
      classpath 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.0.32'
   }
}
plugins {
   id 'java'
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.4'
   id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.company'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
   mavenLocal()
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq'
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
   implementation 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.18.0'
   implementation 'org.jooq:jooq:3.18.0'
   implementation 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.0.32'
   testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
   testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
   testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.0.4'
}


import org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool;
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.*


GenerationTool.generate(new Configuration()
      .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
            .withDriver('com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver')
            .withUrl('jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db')
            .withUser('root')
            .withPassword('root'))
      .withGenerator(new Generator()
            .withDatabase(new Database())
            .withGenerate(new Generate()
                  .withPojos(true)
                  .withDaos(true))
            .withTarget(new Target()
                  .withPackageName('com.example.employee')
                  .withDirectory('src/main'))))
```

New to this, if anyone could point me what I am doing wrong or where I should learn about this it would be really helpful.

Comment: What console output are you seeing?

Comment: It just says build is successfull and Spring boot application starts with no errors.

Comment: Any reason you omitted the `apply plugin: 'java'` line from the docs? Does that make a change?

Comment: I have used the plugin{} section to include java. I tried, either way, same issue. :(

Comment: Hmm, that section of the manual had been written a while ago. Perhaps, Gradle has changed things for builds that contain scripts like this. It has never been a really clean way to use jOOQ in Gradle. Perhaps, you should try using the recommended third party plugin after all? I'm afraid I can't allocate too much time to this right now, you'll probably be faster trying the third party plugin.